# How to show that the element is not mapped to anything

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to show informally a partial function in terms of mappings (not mentioning the function symbol or its domain, etc.)

a ↦ b, c ↦ e,

What is the best practice to informally show unmapped elements? 
My current versions are:

1. d ↦ ⊥
2. d ↦ ∅

(2) is nice because it intuitively says that `d` is mapped to `nothing`, but it says that it is mapped to a set while all other elements are mapped to variables.

(1) is nice because it shows that d is mapped to some distinguished entity (falsity), not a set. But this might be bit confusing as not may knows what `bottom` is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I worry about both being accidentally interpreted as $d$ being actually *mapped* to the respective symbols.  There is nothing stopping $\emptyset$ from being an element of the codomain.  Instead, I might have opted to do something more like $d\not\mapsto$ if I were to do an informal shorthand, or $d\not\mapsto y~\forall y$ for a bit longer informal shorthand.  As for a formal way of writing it, your "partial function" is in essence a relation, $\mathcal{R}\subseteq X\times Y$ for some domain $X$ and codomain $Y$, $d$ not mapping to anything is that $(d,y)\not\in\mathcal{R}$ for any $y\in Y$.

Comment: That being said, there is nothing wrong with *using words and natural language*.  Things don't necessarily have to have symbols.  The phrase "$d$ *doesn't map to anything*" is perfectly understandable and concise.

Comment: not d -> or d not ->